# Frontend for CRUD operations Postgres

Tags: open-source, database, web, postgresql

I need a frontend for CRUD Operations on a Postgres database. It has to be understandable also for persons without database background.

Also it would be nice if it is open source and free (and maybe web-based). I've tried with LibreOffice Base and with forms, but struggling with the following problem:

I have a "main"-table 'Person', a table 'Hobby' and a table 'Friends', all holding an ID (as PK) and several attributes.

To insert data into 'Person', I found the forms very easy to use.
But if I want to add Hobbies and Friends to Persons, the problems begin.

Since I found that in Postgres there is no possibility to store something like an array of foreign keys (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156695/postgres-creating-a-table-with-an-array-of-foreign-keys) I modelled it in the database scheme as e.g. 'Person_has_Hobby' relation that holds foreign keys from persons and hobbies.

So manually inserting or editing is not the problem.

How can I get this kind of mapping in an easy useable way (WYSIWYG and maybe webbased, programming language is secondary for the moment)?